# Raspivid stdout hangs after random interval in Node and Python

Tags: python, streaming-video, node.js, raspivid

Around 2 years ago, I made a simple server in Node.JS, running on a RPi Zero W, that started a raspivid process and captured MJPEG frames from the output. These were send to a website using a websocket.

I wanted to rework my setup to work via HTTP recently. But after updating my RPi and rewriting my setup, I noticed some weird behaviour. After starting either my old (websocket) server or my new (http) server, Raspivid would stop providing data to Node after a random amount of minutes. I'm 100% certain this wasn't an issue in the past, because I'd let it run for multiple hours, multiple times.

I tried isolating the issue by removing all "unnecessary" parts, keeping only the process spawning:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

//JPEG start byte
const startByte = Buffer.alloc(2);
startByte.writeUInt16LE(0xd8ff, 0);

//Build command
const command = "raspivid";
const args = [];
args.push("-t", "0");
args.push("-w", "1280");
args.push("-h", "720");
args.push("-fps", "30");
args.push("-cd", "MJPEG");
args.push("-n", "-o", "-");

//Spawn process
const process = spawn(command, args, {stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'ignore']});

//Data event
let buffer = Buffer.alloc(0);
process.stdout.on("data", data => {
    buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, data]);

    //Look for end byte in buffer
    const index = buffer.lastIndexOf(startByte);
    if (index > 0) {
        const frame = buffer.slice(0, index);
        buffer = buffer.slice(index);
        console.log("got frame: ", frame.length);
    }
});
```

This little bit of code will lock-up eventually (tested on Node 12 and 14). I tried all possible data/error events, but they don't even trigger. After some researching, I found it could be related to buffering. Node doesn't provide any control over this though, so I made a Python variant of the above:

```
import subprocess


def run():
    command = ["raspivid", "-t", "0", "-w", "1280", "-h", "720", "-fps", "30", "-cd", "MJPEG", "-n", "-o", "-"]

    # Run command
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    # Prepare search data
    search_data = 0xd8ff
    search_buffer = search_data.to_bytes(2, byteorder="little", signed=False)

    # Setup
    buffer = bytearray(0)
    check_size = 8 * 1024
    check_current = 0

    # Wait for data
    while True:
        data = process.stdout.read(64)
        buffer.extend(data)

        # Check if we have received enough data to warrant a frame search
        check_current = check_current + len(data)
        if check_current >= check_size:
            frame_idx = buffer.rfind(search_buffer)

            # If JPEG frame found, extract it
            if frame_idx > 0:
                frame = buffer[0:frame_idx]
                buffer = buffer[frame_idx:]
                print("got frame", len(frame))

            # Reset current check value
            check_current = 0


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

The above code does actually seem to work for prolonged periods of time, but there's a catch. Notice the `process.stdout.read(64)`. A value of 64 works, but if I increase this value it will break just like the Node code. The higher, the faster / more likely it is to break. It also eventually breaks when using `.readline()`.

Other factors that seem to increase the likeliness of breaking (unsure however, due to the randomness of it breaking):

- Increasing GPU memory split
- Running the code in a `screen` and detaching

In Python I also tried playing around with the subprocess `bufsize` argument in combination with `read()` block size, but only the above setup seems consistent.

The big issue here is I don't really want to use Python, and also using a block size of 64 increases CPU usage by around 3 times the old solution. The old (Node) setup was around 10-20% CPU, and this setup goes up to 50-60%. Increasing the block size lowers CPU usage but breaks eventually.

Does anyone know why this happens? Or how I could go about fixing it? I'm really not sure what else I can try. Also apologies for the long post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small update on the issue. Finally had some time to look into it some more. Initially I updated Node to the latest LTS and changed my capture implementation to use V4L2 directly, instead of raspivid. This didn't help at all, still the same behaviour.

I figured the problem lied elsewhere, so I started looking at the system configuration and discovered that GPU overclocking and overvolt settings were applied. I don't recall ever setting that, but maybe I just forgot about it.

Anyway, after removing the overclock settings, the problem has completely disappeared. It works like before again :) Kind of a dumb problem, but I'm glad it has been fixed. Also, nice bonus, the direct V4L2 implementation has improved CPU usage. It stays at around 10% now.